Calculating of a cubic root
This is a Halley's method to calculate cubic root of $a$. This iteration converges more quickly than Newton's method.
$$x_{n+1}=x_n\cdot\frac{x_n^3+2a}{2x_n^3+a}$$
The question is, is above iteration is just randomly choosen ? What is mathematical perspective about this ? For example,
$$x_{n+1}=x_n\frac{2x_n^3+a}{x_n^3+2a}$$
doesn't work however $$x\cdot\frac{2x^3+a}{x^3+2a}=x=\sqrt[3]{a}$$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halley%27s_method#Derivation
